# r holtwinters predict

Tags: r, predict

I am using R for sometime now and some days ago I found a very interesting function which made a prediction on a given time series. It just took the data from the known time series and applied it on a given period, but it kept the pattern. The problem is that I lost it. I am sure it was a sort of HoltWinters. I am trying two days to find something, but till now without success. Could someone please give me a hand on this!

Comment: see package `forecast`, Type `library('sos'); findFn('HoltWinters')`

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I am reading the last two days, and I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `predict`:

```
# Assuming you have some timeseries data in myts
hw <- HoltWinters(myts)
predict(hw, 10)   # predict 10 periods ahead
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forecast.HoltWinters`

```
#Model creation
fit <- HoltWinters(ts.data,gamma=FALSE)
#Load forecast package
require(forecast)
#Apply model into forecast
forecast(fit)
```